# Best parallelism for permutation of elements in a list

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, dask

I am trying to make a function that can run in parallel that computes the permutation of the elements of list in a dictionary and returns them in a dictionary. I tried with multiprocessing pool but for some reason, it is even slower. I wonder if there is a way to implement my function using dask.

The function I am trying to run in parallel is permutations:

```
import time
def Joinx(numList):
    '''Convert  numbers of  a list to a only one number
       [1,2,3]=> 123'''
    s = ''.join(map(str, numList))
    return s
def permute(a, l, r,lco):
    if l==r:          
        b=a[:]
        lco[Joinx(a[1:])]=a[:]
    else: 
        for i in range(l,r+1): 
            if i!=l:
                a[0]=(-1)*int(a[0])#Sign for permutation
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] 
            permute(a, l+1, r,lco)             
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]                         
            if i!=l:#Sign for permutation
                a[0]=(-1)*int(a[0])

def permutations(dictx):
    dict_out={}
    for key in dictx:
        element=dictx[key]
        n = len(element)
        permute(element, 1, n-1,dict_out) 
    return dict_out
```

This is a test for my function:

```
test_dic={'a':[-1, 'h', 'g', 'f', 'e'],'b':[1, 'p', 'q', 'r', 's'],'c':[1, 'a', 'u', 'c', 't']}
starttime = time.time()
print(permutations(test_dic))  
print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

the output is this:

```
{'hgfe': [-1, 'h', 'g', 'f', 'e'], 'hgef': [1, 'h', 'g', 'e', 'f'], 'hfge': [1, 'h', 'f', 'g', 'e'], 'hfeg': [-1, 'h', 'f', 'e', 'g'], 'hefg': [1, 'h', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 'hegf': [-1, 'h', 'e', 'g', 'f'], 'ghfe': [1, 'g', 'h', 'f', 'e'], 'ghef': [-1, 'g', 'h', 'e', 'f'], 'gfhe': [-1, 'g', 'f', 'h', 'e'], 'gfeh': [1, 'g', 'f', 'e', 'h'], 'gefh': [-1, 'g', 'e', 'f', 'h'], 'gehf': [1, 'g', 'e', 'h', 'f'], 'fghe': [1, 'f', 'g', 'h', 'e'], 'fgeh': [-1, 'f', 'g', 'e', 'h'], 'fhge': [-1, 'f', 'h', 'g', 'e'], 'fheg': [1, 'f', 'h', 'e', 'g'], 'fehg': [-1, 'f', 'e', 'h', 'g'], 'fegh': [1, 'f', 'e', 'g', 'h'], 'egfh': [1, 'e', 'g', 'f', 'h'], 'eghf': [-1, 'e', 'g', 'h', 'f'], 'efgh': [-1, 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], 'efhg': [1, 'e', 'f', 'h', 'g'], 'ehfg': [-1, 'e', 'h', 'f', 'g'], 'ehgf': [1, 'e', 'h', 'g', 'f'], 'pqrs': [1, 'p', 'q', 'r', 's'], 'pqsr': [-1, 'p', 'q', 's', 'r'], 'prqs': [-1, 'p', 'r', 'q', 's'], 'prsq': [1, 'p', 'r', 's', 'q'], 'psrq': [-1, 'p', 's', 'r', 'q'], 'psqr': [1, 'p', 's', 'q', 'r'], 'qprs': [-1, 'q', 'p', 'r', 's'], 'qpsr': [1, 'q', 'p', 's', 'r'], 'qrps': [1, 'q', 'r', 'p', 's'], 'qrsp': [-1, 'q', 'r', 's', 'p'], 'qsrp': [1, 'q', 's', 'r', 'p'], 'qspr': [-1, 'q', 's', 'p', 'r'], 'rqps': [-1, 'r', 'q', 'p', 's'], 'rqsp': [1, 'r', 'q', 's', 'p'], 'rpqs': [1, 'r', 'p', 'q', 's'], 'rpsq': [-1, 'r', 'p', 's', 'q'], 'rspq': [1, 'r', 's', 'p', 'q'], 'rsqp': [-1, 'r', 's', 'q', 'p'], 'sqrp': [-1, 's', 'q', 'r', 'p'], 'sqpr': [1, 's', 'q', 'p', 'r'], 'srqp': [1, 's', 'r', 'q', 'p'], 'srpq': [-1, 's', 'r', 'p', 'q'], 'sprq': [1, 's', 'p', 'r', 'q'], 'spqr': [-1, 's', 'p', 'q', 'r'], 'auct': [1, 'a', 'u', 'c', 't'], 'autc': [-1, 'a', 'u', 't', 'c'], 'acut': [-1, 'a', 'c', 'u', 't'], 'actu': [1, 'a', 'c', 't', 'u'], 'atcu': [-1, 'a', 't', 'c', 'u'], 'atuc': [1, 'a', 't', 'u', 'c'], 'uact': [-1, 'u', 'a', 'c', 't'], 'uatc': [1, 'u', 'a', 't', 'c'], 'ucat': [1, 'u', 'c', 'a', 't'], 'ucta': [-1, 'u', 'c', 't', 'a'], 'utca': [1, 'u', 't', 'c', 'a'], 'utac': [-1, 'u', 't', 'a', 'c'], 'cuat': [-1, 'c', 'u', 'a', 't'], 'cuta': [1, 'c', 'u', 't', 'a'], 'caut': [1, 'c', 'a', 'u', 't'], 'catu': [-1, 'c', 'a', 't', 'u'], 'ctau': [1, 'c', 't', 'a', 'u'], 'ctua': [-1, 'c', 't', 'u', 'a'], 'tuca': [-1, 't', 'u', 'c', 'a'], 'tuac': [1, 't', 'u', 'a', 'c'], 'tcua': [1, 't', 'c', 'u', 'a'], 'tcau': [-1, 't', 'c', 'a', 'u'], 'tacu': [1, 't', 'a', 'c', 'u'], 'tauc': [-1, 't', 'a', 'u', 'c']}
That took 0.0007135868072509766 seconds
```

My dictionary for can be really big. A example with a larget set will be:

```
    Dic_Dd= {10169012: [  1, 3001016, 3009012,1002,1005,1006,2003,
  2004,2015], 20169012: [ -1, 3002016, 3009012,1001,1005,1006,2003,
  2004,2015], 10159012: [ -1, 3001015, 3009012,1002,1005,1006,2003,
  2004,2016], 20159012: [  1, 3002015, 3009012,1001,1005,1006,2003,
  2004,2016], 10162009: [ -1, 3001016, 3002009,1005,1006,1012,2003,
  2004,2015], 10092016: [  1, 3001009, 3002016,1005,1006,1012,2003,
  2004,2015], 10152009: [  1, 3001015, 3002009,1005,1006,1012,2003,
  2004,2016], 10092015: [ -1, 3001009, 3002015,1005,1006,1012,2003,
  2004,2016], 101620159012: [ -1, 3001016, 3002015, 3009012,1005,1006,2003,
  2004], 101520169012: [  1, 3001015, 3002016, 3009012,1005,1006,2003,
  2004], 10093012: [ -1, 3001009, 3003012,1002,1005,1006,2004,
  2015,2016], 10094012: [  1, 3001009, 3004012,1002,1005,1006,2003,
  2015,2016], 20093012: [  1, 3002009, 3003012,1001,1005,1006,2004,
  2015,2016], 20094012: [ -1, 3002009, 3004012,1001,1005,1006,2003,
  2015,2016], 10163005: [ -1, 3001016, 3003005,1002,1006,1012,2004,
  2009,2015], 10163006: [  1, 3001016, 3003006,1002,1005,1012,2004,
  2009,2015], 10164005: [  1, 3001016, 3004005,1002,1006,1012,2003,
  2009,2015], 10164006: [ -1, 3001016, 3004006,1002,1005,1012,2003,
  2009,2015], 10165015: [  1, 3001016, 3005015,1002,1006,1012,2003,
  2004,2009], 10166015: [ -1, 3001016, 3006015,1002,1005,1012,2003,
  2004,2009], 20163005: [  1, 3002016, 3003005,1001,1006,1012,2004,
  2009,2015], 20163006: [ -1, 3002016, 3003006,1001,1005,1012,2004,
  2009,2015], 20164005: [ -1, 3002016, 3004005,1001,1006,1012,2003,
  2009,2015], 20164006: [  1, 3002016, 3004006,1001,1005,1012,2003,
  2009,2015], 20165015: [ -1, 3002016, 3005015,1001,1006,1012,2003,
  2004,2009], 20166015: [  1, 3002016, 3006015,1001,1005,1012,2003,
  2004,2009], 10153005: [  1, 3001015, 3003005,1002,1006,1012,2004,
  2009,2016], 20153005: [ -1, 3002015, 3003005,1001,1006,1012,2004,
  2009,2016], 10153006: [ -1, 3001015, 3003006,1002,1005,1012,2004,
  2009,2016], 20153006: [  1, 3002015, 3003006,1001,1005,1012,2004,
  2009,2016], 10154005: [ -1, 3001015, 3004005,1002,1006,1012,2003,
  2009,2016], 10154006: [  1, 3001015, 3004006,1002,1005,1012,2003,
  2009,2016], 10155016: [ -1, 3001015, 3005016,1002,1006,1012,2003,
  2004,2009], 10156016: [  1, 3001015, 3006016,1002,1005,1012,2003,
  2004,2009], 20154005: [  1, 3002015, 3004005,1001,1006,1012,2003,
  2009,2016], 20154006: [ -1, 3002015, 3004006,1001,1005,1012,2003,
  2009,2016], 20155016: [  1, 3002015, 3005016,1001,1006,1012,2003,
  2004,2009], 20156016: [ -1, 3002015, 3006016,1001,1005,1012,2003,
  2004,2009], 101620153005: [  1, 3001016, 3002015, 3003005,1006,1012,2004,
  2009], 101620153006: [ -1, 3001016, 3002015, 3003006,1005,1012,2004,
  2009], 101620154005: [ -1, 3001016, 3002015, 3004005,1006,1012,2003,
  2009], 101620154006: [  1, 3001016, 3002015, 3004006,1005,1012,2003,
  2009], 101630054006: [ -1, 3001016, 3003005, 3004006,1002,1012,2009,
  2015], 101630056015: [ -1, 3001016, 3003005, 3006015,1002,1012,2004,
  2009], 101630064005: [  1, 3001016, 3003006, 3004005,1002,1012,2009,
  2015], 101630065015: [  1, 3001016, 3003006, 3005015,1002,1012,2004,
  2009], 101640056015: [  1, 3001016, 3004005, 3006015,1002,1012,2003,
  2009], 101640065015: [ -1, 3001016, 3004006, 3005015,1002,1012,2003,
  2009], 101520163005: [ -1, 3001015, 3002016, 3003005,1006,1012,2004,
  2009], 101520163006: [  1, 3001015, 3002016, 3003006,1005,1012,2004,
  2009], 101520164005: [  1, 3001015, 3002016, 3004005,1006,1012,2003,
  2009], 101520164006: [ -1, 3001015, 3002016, 3004006,1005,1012,2003,
  2009], 201630054006: [  1, 3002016, 3003005, 3004006,1001,1012,2009,
  2015], 201630056015: [  1, 3002016, 3003005, 3006015,1001,1012,2004,
  2009], 201630064005: [ -1, 3002016, 3003006, 3004005,1001,1012,2009,
  2015], 201630065015: [ -1, 3002016, 3003006, 3005015,1001,1012,2004,
  2009], 201640056015: [ -1, 3002016, 3004005, 3006015,1001,1012,2003,
  2009], 201640065015: [  1, 3002016, 3004006, 3005015,1001,1012,2003,
  2009], 101530054006: [  1, 3001015, 3003005, 3004006,1002,1012,2009,
  2016], 101530056016: [  1, 3001015, 3003005, 3006016,1002,1012,2004,
  2009], 201530054006: [ -1, 3002015, 3003005, 3004006,1001,1012,2009,
  2016], 201530056016: [ -1, 3002015, 3003005, 3006016,1001,1012,2004,
  2009], 101530064005: [ -1, 3001015, 3003006, 3004005,1002,1012,2009,
  2016], 101530065016: [ -1, 3001015, 3003006, 3005016,1002,1012,2004,
  2009], 201530064005: [  1, 3002015, 3003006, 3004005,1001,1012,2009,
  2016], 201530065016: [  1, 3002015, 3003006, 3005016,1001,1012,2004,
  2009], 101540056016: [ -1, 3001015, 3004005, 3006016,1002,1012,2003,
  2009], 101540065016: [  1, 3001015, 3004006, 3005016,1002,1012,2003,
  2009], 201540056016: [  1, 3002015, 3004005, 3006016,1001,1012,2003,
  2009], 201540065016: [ -1, 3002015, 3004006, 3005016,1001,1012,2003,
  2009], 1016201530054006: [  1, 3001016, 3002015, 3003005, 3004006,1012,2009], 1016201530064005: [ -1, 3001016, 3002015, 3003006, 3004005,1012,2009], 1015201630054006: [ -1, 3001015, 3002016, 3003005, 3004006,1012,2009], 1015201630064005: [  1, 3001015, 3002016, 3003006, 3004005,1012,2009], 30125016: [  1, 3003012, 3005016,1001,1002,1006,2004,
  2009,2015], 30126016: [ -1, 3003012, 3006016,1001,1002,1005,2004,
  2009,2015], 30125015: [ -1, 3003012, 3005015,1001,1002,1006,2004,
  2009,2016], 30126015: [  1, 3003012, 3006015,1001,1002,1005,2004,
  2009,2016], 30124005: [ -1, 3003012, 3004005,1001,1002,1006,2009,
  2015,2016], 30124006: [  1, 3003012, 3004006,1001,1002,1005,2009,
  2015,2016], 40125016: [ -1, 3004012, 3005016,1001,1002,1006,2003,
  2009,2015], 40126016: [  1, 3004012, 3006016,1001,1002,1005,2003,
  2009,2015], 40125015: [  1, 3004012, 3005015,1001,1002,1006,2003,
  2009,2016], 40126015: [ -1, 3004012, 3006015,1001,1002,1005,2003,
  2009,2016], 30054012: [  1, 3003005, 3004012,1001,1002,1006,2009,
  2015,2016], 30064012: [ -1, 3003006, 3004012,1001,1002,1005,2009,
  2015,2016], 301250166015: [ -1, 3003012, 3005016, 3006015,1001,1002,2004,
  2009], 301240065016: [ -1, 3003012, 3004006, 3005016,1001,1002,2009,
  2015], 301250156016: [  1, 3003012, 3005015, 3006016,1001,1002,2004,
  2009], 301240056016: [  1, 3003012, 3004005, 3006016,1001,1002,2009,
  2015], 301240065015: [  1, 3003012, 3004006, 3005015,1001,1002,2009,
  2016], 301240056015: [ -1, 3003012, 3004005, 3006015,1001,1002,2009,
  2016], 401250166015: [  1, 3004012, 3005016, 3006015,1001,1002,2003,
  2009], 300640125016: [  1, 3003006, 3004012, 3005016,1001,1002,2009,
  2015], 401250156016: [ -1, 3004012, 3005015, 3006016,1001,1002,2003,
  2009], 300540126016: [ -1, 3003005, 3004012, 3006016,1001,1002,2009,
  2015], 300640125015: [ -1, 3003006, 3004012, 3005015,1001,1002,2009,
  2016], 300540126015: [  1, 3003005, 3004012, 3006015,1001,1002,2009,
  2016]}
```

Comment: Is `test_dic` your real dataset? For such a tiny input, by the time the OS manages to spawn another process or two and let them begin work, the single threaded version will long since have finished and been relaxing on the beach drinking a cool beverage. Also, I don't see any multiprocessing at all in this code. Can you clarify? Thanks. PS--`itertools.permutations` is really good and really fast.

Comment: No, the real data set can have over a million lists and the list can be of different sizes.

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour section [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We expect to see an honest attempt at solution, as well as a clear specification of the problem.  Your small example contains no attempt at parallelization, and you have neglected to describe any of the scaling factors that would go into the design of such an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to consider your system configuration; there is no "best parallelism", as your title suggests.  How many processors do you have?  Is it fixed, or a parameter of your algorithm?  What memory is available for each?

For most such straightforward applications, the "best" way is usually to simply allocate the tasks equally to the processors.  If you have a million such tasks and four processors, slice your structure into quarters, and spawn a separate process for the surplus quarters, running one quarter in the parent thread.

Answer (score 0):

These are my two different implementations with dask:

```
import time
import dask
def Joinx(numList):
    '''Convert  numbers of  a list to a only one number
       [1,2,3]=> 123'''
    s = ''.join(map(str, numList))
    return s

def permute(a, l, r,lco):
    if l==r:          
        b=a[:]
        lco[Joinx(a[1:])]=a[:]

    else: 
        for i in range(l,r+1): 
            if i!=l:
                a[0]=(-1)*int(a[0])#Sign for permutation
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] 
            permute(a, l+1, r,lco)            
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]                         
            if i!=l:#Sign for permutation
                a[0]=(-1)*int(a[0])


def permutations(element):
    dict_out={}
    n = len(element)
    permute(element, 1, n-1,dict_out)
    return dict_out

def comp(dics):
    lst=[]   
    for elem in dics:
        per=dask.delayed(permutations)(dics[elem])
        lst.append(per)
    return dask.compute(*lst)

test_dic={'a':[-1, 'h', 'g', 'f', 'e'],'b':[1, 'p', 'q', 'r', 's'],'c':[1, 'a', 'u', 'c', 't']}
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
client = Client()
starttime = time.time()
dfl=comp(test_dic)
print(dfl)  
print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

Time:  0.023533344268798828 seconds

```
from dask.delayed import delayed
def Joinx(numList):
    '''Convert  numbers of  a list to a only one number
       [1,2,3]=> 123'''
    s = ''.join(map(str, numList))
    return s

def permute(a, l, r,lco):
    if l==r:          
        b=a[:]
        lco[Joinx(a[1:])]=a[:]
    else: 
        for i in range(l,r+1): 
            if i!=l:
                a[0]=(-1)*int(a[0])#Sign for permutation
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l] 
            permute(a, l+1, r,lco)             
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]                         
            if i!=l:#Sign for permutation
                a[0]=(-1)*int(a[0])
@delayed
def permutations(dictx):
    dict_out={}#dask.delayed({})
    for key in dictx:
        element=dictx[key]
        n = len(element)
        permute(element, 1, n-1,dict_out) 
    return dict_out
client = Client()
test_dic={'a':[-1, 'h', 'g', 'f', 'e'],'b':[1, 'p', 'q', 'r', 's'],'c':[1, 'a', 'u', 'c', 't']}
from dask.distributed import Client, progress
starttime = time.time()
print(dask.compute(permutations(test_dic)))  
print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

Time: 0.01705622673034668 seconds

When the dictionary is large these implementations are faster compared to the no parallel implementation